# Why this code gives run time error on mid calculation?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main() {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 2;
    int ret1 = 0;
    int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
    ret1 = mid;

    return ret1;
}
```

Why is this code giving runtime error?
https://ideone.com/iAdQO0

Comment: I would guess that is because your main function returned something other than 0.

Comment: This is working as expected.

Comment: A tip for code formatting. Copy it from your IDE or text editor and paste it into Stack Overflow. Then select all the code and click the format button for "Code" which will add the four spaces in front of each line that Markdown wants.

Comment: "**code** gives run time error" or is it the **OS/shell** that is reporting the error?  What is the _exact_ error messgae?

Comment: FYI, your ideone link has different code than your question. It assigns 0 to the return value instead of `mid`.

Comment: There is no runtime error.    Your `main()` function returns a non-zero value.    A number of user environments (e.g.  various shells under most flavours of unix, the windows command interpreter) deem a non-zero return as an error code and - by default - they report an error in response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nonzero return code from main() indicates an error to many operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

Because any return from main that is not 0 indicates a runtime error.

Comment: Formally it does't. It indicates program's execution result with predefined  values  of success and failure. A run-time error is a catastrophic failure where execution didn't finish. if ideone's devs didn't draw distinction between those, that's their problem (there is way to trap such errors on some OSes)

Comment: Is there formal documentation to support your claim that `main()` returning a non zero value _"indicates a runtime error"_. If so, your answer should have linked to that.